# Erro relativo a quantidade de parametros em Query quando não se usa Query, o que está de errado?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

Estou tendo dificuldade em usar o Hiberante/JPA com chave compostas, acredito que o problema esteja ai, apesar do stacktrace da excessão gerada apontar para outro lugar que não está superficialmente relacionado ao problema.

Já pesquisei na internet sobre o erro especifico:

```
Parameter index out of range (6 > number of parameters, which is 5).
```

Eu usava uma chave composta de 5 chaves estrangeiras, e o erro ocorria também porém informando que o número de parâmetros eram 9 e devia ser 8, procurei na internet e não achei nada que seja relacionado a forma que estou usando o Hibernate, já que este erro ocorre normalmente quando se faz referencia a parametros em queries, o que não é meu caso.

Como pode ser visto no código abaixo estou tentando persistir um objeto relativamente complexo que envolve diversos relacionamentos muitos para um (Many-to-One) e nesta versão dois deles compõe a chave principal (primary-key)

Abaixo segue o resumo das classes usadas no sistema e por último o stacktrace quando tento salvar a entidade.

**PostDataQualification, tento salvar esta classe:**

```
@Entity
@IdClass(PostDataQualificationID.class)
public class PostDataQualification {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idLearningProcess", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer idLearningProcess;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "idPostData", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer idPostData;

    @Column(name = "pontuation", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = true)
    private Integer pontuation;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date date;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "idLearningProcess", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private LearningProcess learningProcess;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idPostData", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = true, updatable = false, nullable = false, unique = false)
    private PostData post;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idClassification", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, unique = false)
    private Classification classification;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idContext", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, unique = false)
    private Context context;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idEvent", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false, unique = false)
    private Event event;
```

**ID composto da classe acima:**

```
public class PostDataQualificationID implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1614666992682125782L;

    private Integer idLearningProcess;
    private Integer idPostData;
```

**LearningProcess**

```
@Entity
public class LearningProcess {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Autor
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {}, optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "type", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, updatable = true, insertable = true)
    private LearningType type;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    Date date;

    @Column(length = 250)
    String shortDescription; // descrição curta do processo de treinamento
    @Column(length = 500)
    String description; // descrição em detalhes do processo de treinamento

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "learningProcess")
    private Set<PostDataQualification> qualification;
```

**PostData**

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = PostData.NAMED_QUERY_FIND_ORIGINAL_ID, query = "SELECT pd FROM PostData pd WHERE pd.idOriginal = ?"),
        @NamedQuery(name = PostData.NAMED_QUERY_FIND_SCREEN_NAME, query = "SELECT pd FROM PostData pd JOIN  pd.sourceProfile sp WHERE sp.screenName = ?") })
public class PostData implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7369168234620318745L;
    public static final String NAMED_QUERY_FIND_ORIGINAL_ID = "PostData.findByOriginalId";
    public static final String NAMED_QUERY_FIND_SCREEN_NAME = "PostData.findByScreenName";
    /**
     * 
     */

    /**
     * ID no banco de dados, não confundir com o ID original do post.
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    /**
     * texto integral do post
     * 
     * Apesar de algumas redes como Twitter permitir apenas 140 caracteres,
     * estou considerando o uso de outras redes qeu permitem posts bem maiores.
     */
    @Column(length = 512)
    private String data;

    /**
     * ID Original do POST conforme fornecido pela Rede Social.
     */
    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String idOriginal;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Autor
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idSourceProfile", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = true, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.PROVIDER_DEFAULT) )
    private Profile sourceProfile;

    // bi-directional many-to-many association to SLAContext
    /**
     * lista os contextos ao qual este post pertence, para cadastrar este post a
     * um novo contexto, basta adicionar o post ao contexto.
     */
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "posts", cascade = {}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Context> contexts;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Autor
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "lang", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = true, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.PROVIDER_DEFAULT) )
    private Language lang = new Language("pt", "Português");

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "posts", cascade = {}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Acquisition> acquisitions;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = true, updatable = false)
    private Date createAt;
```

**SQL gerado durante o ato de persistir a Entidade PostDataQualification:**

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        classifica_.id,
        classifica_.description as descript2_3_,
        classifica_.name as name3_3_ 
    from
        Classification classifica_ 
    where
        classifica_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        PostDataQualification
        (idClassification, idContext, date, idLearningProcess, idPostData) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Código usado para persistir a entidade:

```
    ObservableList<PostDataQualification> l_items = tableView.getItems();
    pm.beginTransaction();
    l_items.forEach(pdq -> {
        log.info(pdq.toString());
        if (pdq.getClassification() != null) {
            pm.persist(pdq);
            pm.flush();
        }
    });
    pm.commitTransaction();
```

Exception Lançada:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1770)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8390)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3758)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$210/34139361.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1765)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.socialsla.persistence.entity.PostDataQualification]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1303)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.AbstractBeanInstance.invoke(AbstractBeanInstance.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
    at org.jboss.weld.proxies.org$jboss$weld$beanProducerMethod-com$socialsla$persistence$factories$SLAEntityManagerFactorymethod_createEntityManager()_$$_WeldClientProxy.flush(org$jboss$weld$beanProducerMethod-com$socialsla$persistence$factories$SLAEntityManagerFactorymethod_createEntityManager()_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at com.socialsla.persistence.PersistenceManager.flush(PersistenceManager.java:403)
    at com.socialsla.gui.controllers.ManualClassificationController.lambda$7(ManualClassificationController.java:512)
    at com.socialsla.gui.controllers.ManualClassificationController$$Lambda$435/1969723339.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at com.socialsla.gui.controllers.javafx.PostDataQualificationObservableList.forEach(PostDataQualificationObservableList.java:417)
    at com.socialsla.gui.controllers.ManualClassificationController.saveAllPostDataQualification(ManualClassificationController.java:508)
    at com.socialsla.gui.controllers.ManualClassificationController.handleSave(ManualClassificationController.java:246)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.socialsla.persistence.entity.PostDataQualification]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2848)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3323)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:333)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:335)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1224)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (6 > number of parameters, which is 5).
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1094)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:997)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:983)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:928)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3688)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3670)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3715)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setNull(PreparedStatement.java:3755)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeSet(ComponentType.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrateId(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2574)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2542)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2820)
    ... 82 more
```

Comment: Um colega no grupo CEJUG conseguiu me ajudar, a solução está em usar as anotações @Id diretamente no relacionamento, eliminando a redundância dos campos, os códigos estão neste Gist: https://gist.github.com/carlosdelfino/f8a2ba9df8b4b62788cb

Answer (score 0):

Olhando seu código não parece ter nada errado.
Mas tem um jeito de alterar o sql sem alterar o seu código, usando o EmbeddedId.

Crie uma classe que represente, com seus atributos, a chave da tabela, marque-a com a anotação *@Embeddable* e implemente Serializable.

E depois crie um atributo na sua entity do tipo da classe recém-criada e marque-a com *@EmbeddedId.*

Quem sabe mudando um pouco o SQL o problema não se resolva.

Comment: Um colega no grupo CEJUG conseguiu me ajudar, a solução está em usar as anotações @Id diretamente no relacionamento, eliminando a redundância dos campos, os códigos estão neste Gist: https://gist.github.com/carlosdelfino/f8a2ba9df8b4b62788cb